# NSBundle mainBundle not found

Tags: ios, xcode, nsbundle, mainbundle

I'm using the split view template on the iPad.

In my `MasterViewController` the code:

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

works.

In my `DetailViewController` the same code shows an error? I imported `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`. It knows `NSBundle` but does not recognize `mainBundle` for whatever reason.

Would be nice if so. could help me!

[image: Error]

`Missing "[" at start of message send expression`

**EDIT**

**ANSWER:**

I forgot the brackets. It's in a case-statement. So use:

```
case 1:
{
   //bla ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you use this code in a header file? Could you paste the code where this error happens?

Comment: No, it's used in the `.m` file. Sorry for the confusion. I edited my answer. I want to initialize a `NSURL` for a `MPMediaPlayerController`.

Comment: What't the exact error text you're seeing?

Comment: Copy and pasted text is a lot easier to work with that an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case statements if a variable is declared braces are required around the statement, this is just plain "C" syntax.

Fixed:

```
switch (sender.row) {
    case 1:
    {
        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testclip" ofType:@"mov"]];
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    }
}
```

I changed `MoviePlayerController` to `MPMoviePlayerController` assuming that is what the op meant. I also added the missing `player` variable.

Comment: Yep. I found out by myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add curly braces inside the case's if you're going to declare new variables.

This code won't compile

```
case 1:
     NSURL *foo;
```

This will:

```
case 1:
{
    NSURL *foo;
}
```